# filter an array with same elements

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter an array with the same elements by using the `indexOf` function. But it fails and I do not understand why. To be more clear I want to filter by giving the position of an element, but it fails in array with two same elements. Could you please help ?

```
words = ['One', 'Two', 'myWord', 'Three', 'myWord', 'Four'];
    
words = words.filter(item => words.indexOf(item) != 2);
console.log(words);
// expected output: Array ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'myWord', 'Four'],
// the first myWord in position 2 is excluded but not the one in position 4
```

Comment: Do you mean, you are trying to remove duplicates from your array?

Comment: `[...new Set(['myWord', 'myWord'])]`

Comment: `indexOf` returns the *first* index the argument appears in, which in this case is always 0 no matter how many times you repeat the word. Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: If you want the element in position 0, just use `words[0]`. Why do you want to use `filter` for this?

Comment: JavaScript can't differentiate between identical instances of the same primitive value. Even if your code worked, there wouldn't be any way to distinguish the two results. Again, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe an example with more than two items would help?

Comment: I edited the example I run. Could you please check it out

Comment: Ok, it wasn't clear that the array could have different elements in it, that makes more sense now.

Comment: Thank you for the understanding. I am very sorry for that. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `filter` for this. To remove an element at a specific index, just use `array.splice(index, 1)`.

```js
const words = ['One', 'Two', 'myWord', 'Three', 'myWord', 'Four']
words.splice(2, 1)
console.log(words)

const words2 = ['One', 'Two', 'myWord', 'Three', 'myWord', 'Four']
words2.splice(4, 1)
console.log(words2)
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining how `array.splice` and its arguments work.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the index of an element is equal to the index of its first occurrence and keep only those elements.

```js
words = ['myWord', 'myWord'];

words = words.filter((item,idx) => words.indexOf(item) === idx);

console.log(words);
```

You could also use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which is a more efficient data structure that doesn't allow duplicates.

```js
words = ['myWord', 'myWord'];

words = [...new Set(words)];

console.log(words);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the items in your array are identical, `indexOf` always returns `0` for each item filtered. `0 != 1` always evaluates to `true`. Since you always return `true` from filter, you effectively are doing `words.filter(item => true)` and filtering nothing.

May I ask what your intention is here? are you trying to uniqueify the array?

Comment: I just want to extract the rest of the array, appart from position 1

Comment: @Apostolos Could you clarify what exactly you want?

Comment: I edited the example I run. Could you please check it out

Answer (score 0):

if What You need is really filter for a specific position then

```
const index = 2
words = words.filter((item, i) => i != index);
```

but it does not perform so well since has to loop over all the elements, I would opt for something like the following:

```
words = [...words.slice(0, index), ...words.slice(index+1)]
```

they behave the same as long as `index >= 0` so a wrapping function would be a good thing.

There is any particular reason why You want to use `indexOf` ?